# How to disable syntax highlight on Windows 10 PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I want to disable syntax highlight on windows 10 power shell.

How I can do it?
There is no menu to disable it on preference.

Note that I using windows 10 (Anniversary updated)

Comment: `Remove-Module PSReadline`

Comment: or (if you want to keep other `PSReadline` features): `[Microsoft.PowerShell.TokenClassification].GetEnumValues() | % { Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind $_ -ForegroundColor (Get-PSReadlineOption).DefaultTokenForegroundColor }`.

Comment: @PetSerAl: put that as an ans. I will upvote it buddy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As by default syntax highlighting provided by `PSReadline` module, then you need to remove `PSReadline` module from your PowerShell session:

```
Remove-Module PSReadline
```

or, if you want to use other `PSReadline` features (like persistent history) you can configure syntax highlighting to use same color for all kinds of tokens:

```
[Microsoft.PowerShell.TokenClassification].GetEnumValues() | % { 
    $DefaultColor = (Get-PSReadlineOption).DefaultTokenForegroundColor
} {
    Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind $_ -ForegroundColor $DefaultColor
}
```